# ArcTan and Compile

Tags: compile, trigonometry

See following three snippet code:

```
(*can compile*)
range = Range[-2, 2, 0.005];
Compile[{},
   With[{r = range}, Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, r}, {y, r}]]][];

(*can compile*)
Compile[{}, 
   With[{r = Range[-2, 2, 0.005 - 10^-8]}, Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, r}, {y, r}]]][];

(*can't compile*)
Compile[{},
   With[{r = Range[-2, 2, 0.005]}, Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, r}, {y, r}]]][];
```

Why the last code can't be compiled? I used Mathematica 9.0.1.

Comment: Your first "can compiled" doesn't compile in V.9.0.1. Gives the errors: "CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 12; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>" and "ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered. >>".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to Mr. Wizard's analysis, one can also avoid the indeterminacy by replacing `ArcTan` as follows:

```
Compile[{}, 
   With[{r = Range[-2, 2, 0.005]}, 
    Table[Arg[Complex[x, y]], {x, r}, {y, r}]]][];
```

The fact that `ArcTan[0,0]` is undefined is a real nuisance, and I never saw the point of it because that form of the function is mainly used for practical applications such as plotting, where the purely mathematical reasons against defining that special value don't really bother anyone.

Comment: I didn't know of this workaround.  Nice. +1

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ComplexComponents/Arg/27/02/03/0001/ as well as http://functions.wolfram.com/ComplexComponents/Arg/19/03/0002/

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Could you explain what the links above are intended for?

Comment: @AndreasLauschke I'm guessing you want to confirm the equivalence of the `Arg` and `ArcTan` methods. But the links don't seem to address the discrepancy between the definitions at the origin.

Comment: @Jens: indeed, just the equivalence of the two functions. I'd be glad to remove my comments if you think it's more misleading than helpful.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke It's OK to leave the links for completeness, I'd say.

Comment: `Arg[x + y I]` is faster than `Arg[Complex[x, y]]`.

Comment: @chyanog Thanks - I didn't know that. How did you test this?

Comment: @chyaong My test show the contrary: `Timing[With[{r = Range[-2, 2, 0.005]}, Table[Arg[Complex[x, y]], {x, r}, {y, r}]];]` gives 0.437s on my computer, while `Timing[With[{r = Range[-2, 2, 0.005]}, Table[Arg[x + I y], {x, r}, {y, r}]];]` gives 0.734s

Answer (score 5):

The warning messages tell you:

> CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 33; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
>
> ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered. >>

By using an offset of `10^-8` you avoid having exactly zero in the list, and avoid the error.

The first version does not compile in version 7 so I can't tell you about that one.